# Configmap for a env variable that points to a file

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `env` variable called `app_conf_path` which points to a `\location\file.yaml` which in turn contains all the values required for the application to work.The application needs this `app_conf_path`  which has the location of   `file.yaml` to run the application. How can i create a `configmap` for this type of setup.  Right now i am having that `file.yaml` in a `persistentvolume` and have that `env` variable pointing to that `mountlocation`. I came to know about `configmaps` only recently. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I'd like to help you understand the mechanisms of configmap. Can you tell me what kind of app are you working with? And could you give me an example of how the configuration is described in the file.yaml? This way I can give you an example that is much closer to your use case. For what I read I believe you want to stop mounting the file and use only the configmap object on kubernetes, is it correct?

Comment: yes, i want to stop mounting the `persistentvolume` which has this `file.yaml` and the `file.yaml` is a simple `yaml` file with details of `dbconnectionstrings` and `paths` for other `apps`

Comment: Thank you for the information provided. I noticed you got two new answers, both seems correct, but they lack explanation, references and a full reproducible example. I'm preparing a more detailed answer to help you further expand your knowledge on this matter.

Comment: I'm working on your answer, could you confirm if your app accepts other names for the file.yaml? can it be a file called location/config.data for example? Also, do your app only read data from the file in yaml format? Or can it be a simple file with just `key: value` lines?

Comment: yes `filename` can be anything. app reads only`.yaml` format

Comment: I just posted my answer and saw this comment. It's now a problem because configuration files are by definition only `key:value` pair, that's how they are stored into a configuration map.

Comment: You have two options, either rewrite your app to instead of looking for a yaml format, take only the parameters from the configmap or keep mounting externally the yaml file. I personally believe it would be good in the long run to change this behavior in the app so it will become much easier to maintain and manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a `env` variable called `app_conf_path` which points to a `\location\file.yaml` which in turn contains all the values required for the application to work.The application needs this `app_conf_path` which has the location of `file.yaml` to run the application. How can i create a `configmap` for this type of setup?

I'll begin talking about the concepts of ConfigMaps:

- ConfigMap is a dictionary of configuration settings. It consists of key-value pairs of strings.
- ConfigMaps are useful to keep your code separate from configuration.
- You can generate a configmap [from directories](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-directories), [from literal values](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-literal-values) or what we want: [from a file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files).
- [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) can be treated like a volume in kubernetes:

  > - The data stored in a `ConfigMap` object can be referenced in a volume of type `configMap` and then consumed by containerized applications running in a Pod.
  > - When referencing a `configMap` object, you can simply provide its name in the volume to reference it. You can also customize the path to use for a specific entry in the ConfigMap

**Creating a ConfigMap From File:**

- To create a configmap you run the command:

`kubectl create configmap <CONFIGMAP_NAME> --from-file=/location/file.yaml`

- You can also add more than one file to a single configmap, just repeat the `--from-file` argument, example:

```
kubectl create configmap <CONFIGMAP_NAME> \
--from-file=path/db.properties \
--from-file=path/ui.properties
```

---

> I want to stop mounting the  `persistentvolume`  which has this  `file.yaml`  and the  `file.yaml`  is a simple  `yaml`  file with details of  `dbconnectionstrings`  and  `paths`  for other  `apps`

From the concepts we saw above, your intention to stop having to mount the file to a PV to serve the config file can be fully realized using a `ConfigMap`.

- I'd like to suggest you [The ITHollow ConfigMap Example](https://theithollow.com/2019/02/20/kubernetes-configmaps/). I was going to use it here but your app is already built with a function to look for the configuration file outside. I'll leave this link so you can see how you could use a ConfigMap to other apps that needs external configuration and are not hardcoded to look for it in a specific file.

---

**Reproducible Example:**

- This will be a example to show you how to achieve the portion your question requires.

  - It will be a simple `ubuntu` pod which has a config file mounted in `/tmp/file.yaml` and that file path will be a Env variable called `app_conf_path`.
- First, I'll create a file called `file.yaml` and add 3 values:

```
$ cat file.yaml 
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

**NOTE:** *the name `file.yaml` is not very common, I'm using it to emulate your environment, usually we use something like `app.properties` and it does not require any previous structure, just all values in a `key:value` pair form, like in my example.*

- Now we will create the configmap called `app.config` from the file `file.yaml`. The file is on the same folder I'm running the command, thus I don't have to specify the full path:

```
$ kubectl create configmap app.config --from-file=file.yaml
configmap/app.config created
```

*The filename becomes the reference inside the configmap and will be used later*.

- Let's see the configmap we created:

```
$ kubectl describe configmap app.config
Name:         app.config
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
file.yaml:
----
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3

Events:  <none>
```

- Now your goal is to [add the configmap data to a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume), and add the ENV variable that points `app_conf_path` to `/tmp/file.yaml`, here is the `app-deploy.yaml` for that:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
        args: [ "while true; do sleep 3000; done;" ]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /tmp
        env:
          - name: app_conf_path
            value: "/tmp/file.yaml"
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: app.config
```

**NOTE:** This is a very interesting step. We create a `volume` using the `configmap` and we set the location desired to `mount` that `volume`. Each section of the `configmap` will be a file inside that folder. Since we created it from only 1 file, it's the only file that will be mounted. We also set the `ENV name` you need with the `value` as the path to the file.

- Now let's apply it and open a shell inside the pod with `kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -- /bin/bash` to see our result:

```
$ kubectl apply -f app-deploy.yaml 
deployment.apps/my-app created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-68b5b69fc8-xxqpw   1/1     Running   0          3s

$ kubectl exec -it my-app-68b5b69fc8-xxqpw -- /bin/bash

root@my-app-68b5b69fc8-xxqpw:/# printenv | grep app_conf_path
app_conf_path=/tmp/file.yaml

root@my-app-68b5b69fc8-xxqpw:/# cat $app_conf_path   
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

---

Now we reached the goal of your request.

Inside the pod there is a configuration file called `file.yaml` with the configuration settings we used to generate the config file.

You don't have to worry about creating and maintaining the volume separately.

If you still have any question about it let me know in the comments.

Comment: This is such a wonderful explanation of `configmap` actually when i was trying to give the `filename` i could see the same name being there in `env`. Whether i achieve this or not, i accept this as answer as it gives some detailed explanation of `configmaps`. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Would generally set the config in the configmap like:

```
data:
  file.yaml: |
    # Some config
    # content goes here
```

And then in your pod template you have something like:

```
containers:
- ...
  env:
  - name: app_conf_path
    value: /config/file.yml
  volumeMounts:
  - name: config
    mountPath: /config
volumes:
- name: config
  configMap:
    name: your-configmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Configmaps can be created using either YAML manifests or kubectl.

```
kubectl create configmap app_conf_path --from-file=file.yaml

OR

configmap/configmap-multikeys.yaml 

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app_conf_path

data:
  Key1: very
  Key2: value2
```

`kubectl create -f filename.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busy
spec:
  containers:
    - name: busy
      image: busybox
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: app_conf_path
```

Comment: Getting a weird error
`The ConfigMap "app_conf_path" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "app_conf_path": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')`

Comment: remove underscore (_) from the name and try to create

Comment: will that get mapped correctly? i mean `app_conf_path` is what the app looks for. if we give `app-conf-path` will it work?

Comment: You have to provide the same name in configmap and undet volumes section in pod manifests file.